# What is the difference between using value and valueBinding in ember/handlebars?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

What exactly is the difference between using 'value', eg.:

```
{{input type="text" value=someVariable}}
```

and using 'valueBinding', eg.:

```
{{input type="text" valueBinding=someVariable}}
```

in emberjs/handlebars for binding a variable to an input field?

Answer (score 1):

Not difference. 
But the usage is different: when using valueBinding you need to wrap the variable name between quotes. 
Example:

```
{{view "select" content=names value=selectedName}}
```

Or

```
{{view "select" content=names valueBinding="selectedName"}}
```

Both of them have the same result